# Rating-Feature in MongoDB - Percent and get count for each of their ratings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, average, rating

I have a rating model for my posts and the rating value for them. I would like to receive all ratings (ratings vary from 1 to 5) for each post in the database. I would also like to receive a percentage

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tDvZ8qLQ1m8

My scheme just looks like:

```
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "author": ObjectId("5eefd305d9020c52fd81f80d"),
    "rating": 1,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "rating": 1,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "rating": 1,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "rating": 5,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "rating": 3,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "rating": 2,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "rating": 2,
    
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "post": ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682"),
    "rating": 2,
    
  }
]
```

My Code:

```
  {
    $match: {
      post: ObjectId("5ee40fbc1617af52edf81682")
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "post": "$name",
        "rating": "$rating"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.post",
      "counts": {
        "$push": {
          "rating": "$_id.rating",
          "result": "$count",
          "percent": "percent",
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

My Result:

```
  {
    "_id": null,
    "counts": [
      {
        "percent": "percent",
        "rating": 2,
        "result": 3
      },
      {
        "percent": "percent",
        "rating": 3,
        "result": 1
      },
      {
        "percent": "percent",
        "rating": 5,
        "result": 1
      },
      {
        "percent": "percent",
        "rating": 1,
        "result": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My preferred result

```
  {
    "_id": null,
    "ratingAll": 8,
    "ratingAvg": [[rating-average]],
    "counts": [
      {
        "rating": 1,
        "result": 3,
        "percent": [[percentValue]],
      },
      {
        "rating": 2,
        "result": 3,
        "percent": [[percentValue]],
      },
      {
        "rating": 3,
        "result": 1,
        "percent": [[percentValue]],
      },
      {
        "rating": 4,
        "result": 0,
        "percent": [[percentValue]],
      },
      {
        "rating": 5,
        "result": 1,
        "percent": [[percentValue]],
      }
    ]
  }
]
```